# Display member of class in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two classes:

```
public class Client
    {
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public AboutClient ClientInfo {get; set;}

     public Client (int id, string name, AboutClient aboutClient)
     {
      Id = id;
      Name = name;
      ClientInfo = aboutClient;
     }
    }

 public class AboutClient
    {
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string LastName {get; set;}

     public AboutClient(int id, string lastName)
     {
      Id = id;
      LastName = lastName;
     }
    }
```

I've created a list and bound it to a datagridview

```
    public void BindData()
    {
     List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

     clients.Add(new Client(1, "Joy", new AboutClient(1, "Smith")))

     dataGridViewClient.DataSource = clients;
    }
```

I get the following data in dgw:

```
1       "Joy"      AboutClient
```

How to display AboutClient.LastName instead "AboutClient" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to hide the `ClientInfo` column:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public AboutClient ClientInfo {get; set;}
```

And add a new column that returns the lastname from the client info:

```
public string LastName { get { return ClientInfo.LastName; } }
```

Comment: Add another field is not the best way for me (i have a lot of fields). I thought that there is some attribute, but Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, there's no attribute that does it. You could use @PhatWrat's answer, but it's kind of a misuse of `ToString`..

Comment: If you have a lot of fields that display differently, you could create a wrapper class only for display - a `ClientView` which you pass a `Client` to, and it only exposes display columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `AboutClient`

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return LastName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already have ToString which returns more than 10 fields (Name, Address, Gender and other)